# Bluetooth-serial(iOS) + Rongta RPP200-B - slowly and chopped print

Tags: objective-c, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ios-bluetooth, escpos

I use bluetooth printer Rongta RPP200-B and cordova plugin Bluetooth-serial for printing on mobile devices.

On android devices are everthing ok, but on iOS devices is printing very slowly and chopped, especially images are printing very very slowly. I tried to changed native objective-c implementation of plugin write function, but it didn't bring the expected result.

This is my last implementation of write function in BLE.m. The data are sending to plugin as one bulk and there are splitting to packets and sending on BT source.

```
static const int MAX_BUF_LENGTH = 128;

-(void) write:(NSData *)d
{

    NSInteger data_len = d.length;
    NSData *buffer;
    int i = 0;

    // split data into packets
    for(; i < data_len; i+=MAX_BUF_LENGTH)
    {
        NSInteger remainLength = data_len-i;
        NSInteger bufLen = ((remainLength)>MAX_BUF_LENGTH) ? MAX_BUF_LENGTH:remainLength;
        buffer = [d subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, bufLen)];
        // write packet on BT  
        [self writeValue:serialServiceUUID characteristicUUID:writeCharacteristicUUID p:activePeripheral data:buffer];
    }
}
```

I also tried sending to plugin splitted packets and use default implementation of function, but it was even worse. Here is default implementation.

```
-(void) write:(NSData *)d {
  [self writeValue:serialServiceUUID characteristicUUID:writeCharacteristicUUID p:activePeripheral data:d];
}
```

Do you have any idea what can be help? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @krata, I'm having the same issue. Have you made any progress with this matter?